# How to release / unlock / close clipboard so that other apps won't crash

Tags: c#, concurrency, clipboard

This is how I set the clipboard content (text string) in my C# program:

```
Thread staThread3 = new Thread(
delegate()
{
    try
    { new SetClipboardHelper(DataFormats.Text, s).Go();}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         threadEx = ex;
    }
});
staThread3.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
staThread3.Start();
staThread3.Join();
```

**Question**: Is this a safe way of setting the clipboard or is this piece of code still locking the clipboard for other applications? Could it be that I have to add a statement like

```
staThread3.Abort();
```

== EDIT ==

Based on the comments I would like to precise my question: Is there anything I could add to my code to make it safer for other apps to use the clipboard. I am looking for something like a CloseClipboard to release this ressource for other apps.

Comment: You haven't provided any code that uses the clipboard.  We can't tell if it's "safe" or even correct.

Comment: FWIW if other applications can possibly crash based on another application's use of the clipboard, that's *their* problem.  There's literally nothing you can do to effectively stop an application from crashing because another application used a system-wide, shared, resource.

Comment: Why exactly are you creating a new thread here?

Comment: @Falanwe :  to use the Windows clipboard (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard) you must be calling from a thread running in a STA. 'The STAThreadAttribute marks a thread to use the Single-Threaded COM Apartment if COM is needed'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to minimize the amount of time that you have exclusive use of the clipboard. Typically you want to open, clear, update, close.  Then the clipboard is available for other apps, which will typically be reacting to your update (if you have clipboard viewers running).

If running in a thread causes this to be done slowly, or in a manner that is prone to being interrupted (in favor of your main thread, for example), then you should not do it in a thread.

Other programs should defend themselves against "cannot open clipboard" errors, but you should take care to not hold the clipboard open longer than necessary, and never, ever, cause a WM_DrawClipboard message to be sent until you are done using the clipboard.

Comment: Hi Chris, how to close the clipboard explixitely in C# so that the clipboard is availabe for other apps?